# Conveying "off your rocker" (slang for silly, crazy)

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

If you say (informally) that someone is *[off their rocker](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+her+rocker)*, you mean that that person is crazy, silly, etc.. E.g.

> You're off your rocker if you think I'm going to climb that mountain.

How can one convey the meaning of this idiom in French? For example, is the following phrasing idiomatic (in this context)?

> Tu es hors de toi/Tu es fou/Tu es idiot/Tu es stupide/Tu es bête si tu penses que je vais escalader cette montagne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My proposal:

> Tu es complètement **[maboul](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/maboul/48275)** si tu penses que je vais escalader cette montagne.

I like it because it also conveys the colloquial aspect that "off your rocker" has.

For the record, [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maboul%2C+mabouls&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaboul%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmabouls%3B%2Cc0) is the ngram result for this word (thanks to @Personne for reminding me to add the feminine version too).

[image: maboul]

Answer (score 2):

*hors de toi* means very angry so it does not work here.
*fou* means crazy so it would work, yes.
*idiot*, *stupide* and *bête* mean stupid so that is not the right signification here.

Here are some suggestions for silly/crazy that would work as translation for "off your rocker":

> Tu es dingue (si tu penses que je vais escalader cette montagne.)
>
> Tu es cinglé
>
> Tu es fêlé
>
> Tu es givré
>
> Tu es barjo
>
> Tu es barje
>
> Tu es marteau

This last one is not widely used but sounds funny:

> Tu es frappadingue

Answer (score 2):

**Off your rocker** makes me think about ***être à côté de la plaque***.

In addition, the age and origin of the speaker might matter. e.g.:

Young Parisians:

> *T'es **ouf** si tu crois que je vais escalader cette montagne.*

> *T'es pas un peu **ouf** de croire que je vais escalader cette montagne.*

Marseille:

> *T'y es pas **fada** de croire que je vais me l'escalader cette montagne.*

Bruxelles:

> *Si tu crois que je vais escalader cette montagne, **t'as pas toutes tes frites dans le même sachet !***

;-)

---

And here are Personne's suggestions:

Un peu fin XXe siècle :

> — *T’as **pété un plomb** si tu crois que …*

> — *Faut qu’t’ai **des araignées au plafond** pour croire que …*

> — ***Tu t’sens bien** ? mais tu m’vois grimper cet Everest (ou colline par dérision) à la c.. (1) ?*

> — *Là **tu y-es pas** ! c’est pas [mon truc …| pour moi] cette (1+) ..rie !*

Autres atmosphères:

> — *C’est vraiment **pas dans le mille** cette idée de …*

> — ***Faut pas rêver** mon gars, **redescend sur terre**, tu ne me verras jamais faire çà.*

Comment: Hi @Personne, if you have an answer to give, please use the "answer" feature. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Reyedy — https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne?tab=profile

Answer (score 2):

Quelques autres expressions imagées :

> Tu marches à côté de tes pompes si tu crois ..
>
> Tu te mets le doigt dans l'oeil (jusqu'au cou) si tu crois ... un peu vieilli
>
> Tu divagues

Dans ce genre de situation, on peut s'écarter des chemins battus et essayer de faire preuve d'imagination, pour garder l'image du *off* :

> T'as oublié de brancher la machine à neurones si tu crois ...
>
> T'as oublié d'allumer la lumière au dernier étage si tu crois ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use different words in this context. According to me, these are the most accurate.

1. Tu es **fou** si tu penses que je vais escalader cette montagne.
2. Tu es **malade** si tu penses que je vais escalader cette montagne.
3. *(more slang)* Tu es (complètement) **taré** de penser que je vais escalader cette montagne.

Another formulation (maybe closer to *off your rocker*) is **tomber sur la tête**.

4. **[Ça va pas la tête](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A7a_va_pas_la_t%C3%AAte)** de penser que je vais escalader cette montagne.
5. *(or in a shorter version)* **Ça va pas** de penser que je vais escalader cette montagne.
6. **[T'es tombé sur la tête](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_tomb%C3%A9_sur_la_t%C3%AAte)** si tu penses que je vais escalader cette montagne.

Btw, I think that using *de penser* instead of *si tu penses que* is slighty more appropriate, but *si tu penses que* is really ok.

Comment: Also: *T'es pas un peu ouf de penser...*

Comment: [According to you?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/is-the-phrase-according-to-me-correct).